# how does this while loop work?

Tags: javascript, loops

Can someone please explain how this loop works? I'm having difficulty understanding when it would run the if statement and when it loops back to the while.

```
// keep buying phones while you still have money
while (amount < bank_balance) {
    // buy a new phone!
    amount = amount + PHONE_PRICE;

    // can we afford the accessory?
    if (amount < SPENDING_THRESHOLD) {
        amount = amount + ACCESSORY_PRICE;
    }
}
```

Also, why does it still work without an else component with the if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question tells me that you have not fully understand the `if` and `while` by itself and using them together makes you even confused.

`if` does not always need `else`, if the condition is true execute and if false then do nothing.

```
if(){ //if true doA() and if false, skip it
    doA();
}


if(){//if true doA() and if false, doB()
    doA();
}else{
    doB();
}
```

Simple example

```
int count = 10;

while(count != 0){
    count = count - 1;

    if(count == 8){
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Process:

```
on while check 10 != 0;
count is now 10 - 1
on if check if 9 == 8 // FALSE doesnt do anything

loop back up to while

on while check 9 != 0;
count is now 9 - 1
on if check if 8 == 8 // TRUE do execute
count is now 0

loop back up to while

on while check 0 != 0; // FALSE
OUT OF WHILE AND FINISH
```

Hope this helps